# C# GridView rows added in wrong place?

Tags: c#, gridview, row, addition

I want to add rows to my GridView while the function is running.

Before function for adding rows is called there is always 1 "DATA" row present from previous function.

To add rows I tried to use:

```
int n = grid.Rows.Count;    
grid.Rows.Add("Step" + n.ToString());
```

and I would expect to get rows with labels:

```
Data...    
Step1...
Step2...
Step3...
etc
```

instead I get:

```
Step1...
Step2...
Step3...
etc
Data...
```

(DATA row is pushed to the very bottom, all rows are added above it)
Where is my mistake?

EDIT:
I tried:

```
int n = grid.Rows.Count;
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();         
grid.Rows.Insert(n, row);
grid.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = "Step"+n.ToString();
```

but it bugs out.

Comment: you can use `grid.Rows.InsertAt(DataRow, index);`

Comment: @DotNetDev 
`InsertAt(DataRow, index);` function doesnt seem to exist? 
There is `Insert(rowIndex, DataGridViewRow)` tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can create DataTable and then show it on GridView!
try this:

```
System.Data.DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(string));
...
```

this is creating the rows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
            if(i==0)
               {
                  dr[col1]="Data"
                  dr[col2]= ...
                  dr[col3]= ...
                  ...
               }
             if(i>0)
               {
                  // your code
               }
            table.Rows.Add(dr);
         }
```

to add this table to GridView:

```
DataView dv1 = new DataView(table);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv1;
```

Comment: Not sure if it will work for me, as number of columns is not determined from the start. 
It is determined  when program is finished parsing data from a file and puts in into a `List<string> data` (in a single row), from which I do `data.Count` to get the number of required columns.

From that point I want to display whole 'data' in a row of GridView each time it is requierd in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Insert` to add the records and `Count` for the last position

Something like:

```
grid.Rows.Insert(grid.Rows.Count-1, row);
```